# Not satisfiable 3SAT instance implications

Tags: combinatorics, satisfiability

Suppose we have an instance of *3SAT* that is NOT satisfiable and we say $S$.

If in $S$ there are the following $8$ clauses

$\left(a\vee b\vee c\right)\wedge\left(a\vee\bar{b}\vee c\right)\wedge\left(a\vee b\vee\bar{c}\right)\wedge\left(a\vee\bar{b}\vee\bar{c}\right)\wedge\left(\bar{a}\vee b\vee c\right)\wedge\left(\bar{a}\vee\bar{b}\vee c\right)\wedge\left(\bar{a}\vee b\vee\bar{c}\right)\wedge\left(\bar{a}\vee\bar{b}\vee\bar{c}\right)$

we have that anyway we set the Boolean value of the variables $a,b,c$, there is a clause that is *false*.

If in $S$ instead of $a \vee \bar{b} \vee \bar{c}$ we have

$\left(a\vee e\vee f\right)\wedge\left(a\vee\bar{e}\vee f\right)\wedge\left(a\vee e\vee\bar{f}\right)\wedge\left(a\vee\bar{e}\vee\bar{f}\right)$

this implies that anyway we set the Boolean value of the variables $a,b,c,e,f$, there is a clause that is *false*.

In the first case, we have

$\left(a\vee b\vee c\right)\wedge\left(a\vee b\vee\bar{c}\right)\Rightarrow \left(a\vee b\right)$
$\left(a\vee \bar{b}\vee c\right)\wedge\left(a\vee \bar{b}\vee\bar{c}\right)\Rightarrow \left(a\vee \bar{b}\right)$
$\left(\bar{a}\vee b\vee c\right)\wedge\left(\bar{a}\vee b\vee\bar{c}\right)\Rightarrow \left(\bar{a}\vee b\right)$
$\left(\bar{a}\vee \bar{b}\vee c\right)\wedge\left(\bar{a}\vee \bar{b}\vee\bar{c}\right)\Rightarrow \left(\bar{a}\vee \bar{b}\right)$
and
$\left(a\vee b\right)\wedge\left(a\vee \bar{b}\right)\wedge\left(\bar{a}\vee b\right)\wedge\left(\bar{a}\vee \bar{b}\right)$
is NOT satisfiable.

In the second case, we have

$\left(a\vee e\vee f\right)\wedge\left(a\vee \bar{e}\vee f\right)\Rightarrow \left(a\vee f\right)$
$\left(a\vee e\vee \bar{f}\right)\wedge\left(a\vee \bar{e}\vee\bar{f}\right)\Rightarrow \left(a\vee \bar{f}\right)$
and
$\left(a\vee f\right)\wedge\left(a\vee \bar{f}\right)\Rightarrow a$
and
$a\Rightarrow\left(b\vee c\right)\wedge\left(\bar{b}\vee c\right)\wedge\left(b\vee\bar{c}\right)\wedge\left(\bar{b}\vee\bar{c}\right)$
and this last conjunction is NOT satisfiable.

The question is: given a NOT satisfiable *3SAT* instance, if we apply all possible implications and make the conjunction of the right side of the implications, we get a 2SAT instance (the right side of these impliacations is either the conjunction of two variables or a singol variable); is this 2SAT instance not satisfiable? If it isn't, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing the [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) refutation system, which is complete in the sense that if a CNF is unsatisfiable, then it can be proven using Resolution. Resolution is also implicitly used in most SAT solvers.

The *width* of a Resolution refutation is the maximal number of literals in a clause encountered during the refutation. There are 3CNFs on $n$ variables which require width $\Omega(n)$, for example Tseitin contradictions on 3-regular expanders; see for example Massimo Lauria's [lecture notes](https://www.massimolauria.net/courses/2015.ProofComplexity/lecture3.pdf). This means that *every* Resolution refutation of these 3CNFs *must* contain a clause having $\Omega(n)$ literals.